# How do I keep my Animate running at high resolution?

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I'm building an Animate where I have a 3D plot with some of its parameters changing:

`Animate[SphericalPlot3D[Sin[(3/z)*x], x, y, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]], {z, 1, 5}]`

Whilst it is running through the changes though, the entire plot goes very low-res. How can I ensure that the resolution stays high throughout the animation, and not just when it stops running?

Comment: First try to go to `Edit/Preferences/Appearance/Graphics` and set the `Slider` to "Highest Quality" in case it changes anything :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also fix BoxRatios, PlotRange...

1-way: PerformanceGoal -> "Quality":

```
Animate[SphericalPlot3D[Sin[(3/z)*x], x, y, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7],
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> 1], {z, 
  1, 5}]
```

2-way: specify explicitly options that set the quality:

```
Animate[SphericalPlot3D[Sin[(3/z)*x], x, y, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7],
   BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> 1, PlotPoints -> 30, Mesh -> 10], {z, 
  1, 5}]
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much