# Choppy curves with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

While manipulating the slider in Manipulate[], I experience choppy curves. These do however render correctly after letting go of the slider. The same phenomenon occurs when pressing the + or - button or play-button.

An example of this is shown below.

The question is of course how to avoid this.
Any suggestions?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x] + Sin[a x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.002]], {{a, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

Plot while holding the slider:
[image]

After some seconds a smooth plot is presented:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Applying `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` suggested by kguler solves this problem, however some gaps appear at certain values, see below:
[image]

Comment: Closely related: [45858](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45858/5478) and probably a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8072/5478)

Comment: @Kuba, yes you are correct. However in spite of searching a good while before posting, I didn't find them. How did you find them so fast?

Comment: I knew what to look for so don't blame yourself :)

Comment: Regarding the second problem you can use `ControlActive` to specify sufficiently high `PlotPoints`.  Please see these for an understanding of the problem: [(4572183)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4572183), [(29346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29348)  Also my own answer to: [(8482)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8482)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thank you for the highly instructive links. Again, I'm amazed how you find these links.

Comment: @MathLind I remembered (some of the content of) one of them, and from there I was able work my way to the other two.  If I had remembered my own (simpler) answer first I would have found links to the first two but I did it backward.  Get in the habit of looking at the "Linked" section of the sidebar to the right of a question; sometimes they are only tangentially related but fairly often there is good information, and one link often leads to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the option `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x] + Sin[a x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.002], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {{a, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

From the docs:

[PerformanceGoal > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PerformanceGoal.html)

> The typical default setting for `PerformanceGoal` is
>   `$PerformanceGoal`.

[\$PerformanceGoal > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PerformanceGoal.html)

> The typical default value of `$PerformanceGoal` is
>   `ControlActive["Speed","Quality"]`.

Comment: This solves the issue. But if I set "a" to 89 in your example, I get a big gap around 1<x<1.25 at least on my screen. Do you experience this as well?

Comment: @MathLind, yes i see the same gap (version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8 64bit). See also `a=53`. Setting `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` very high (e.g., `PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 15`)seems to get rid of such gaps -- at the cost of speed, of course.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 5`seems to suffice on my system. The lagging is bearable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PlotPoints` adaptively so to calculate one point per period (aprox)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x] + Sin[a x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.002], 
  PlotPoints -> IntegerPart[10  a/2 Pi] ], {{a, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]