# Simple Sin plot generates unexpected output?

Tags: plotting

I an trying to do a very simple smooth Sin wave...

```
Plot[Sin[ 2 Pi 440 t], {t, 0.0, 0.1}]
```

...but I am getting an unexpectedly non-smooth plot for it...

[image]

What is going on at 0.04 - 0.05 in this plot?

I am using Mathematica 10.0.02 Home.

Thanks!

Comment: The adaptive sampling is non-optimal near the artifact. Use the `PlotPoints` option to increase the number of initial samples, e.g., `PlotPoints->101`.

Comment: See my answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59868/193

Comment: Yup, it's a `PlotPoints` issue. To fix, just increase the number of points sampled.